# Create tokens on HyperLedger Fabric with chaincode

Tags: token, hyperledger-fabric

How do I create tokens similar to ERC20 tokens on HyperLedger Fabric?

I want to create a token on HyperLedger Fabric that is transferable between the users. The functionality should be similar to ERC20 tokens on the Ethereum network although in this specific case the transactions shouldn't be public.

For this reason I would like to use a permissioned network like HyperLedger Fabric. Tokens should be created by one superuser and can be bought from and sold to this superuser for fiat money. The blockchain technology is not needed for trust but I would like to use the ledger functionality to keep track of the tokens.

I've played around with assets on HyperLedger but I don't want to create an asset that represents one token. This would mean that transfering 10 tokens requires 10 transactions of assets with an unique id. The ERC20 mechanism where a user has a balance sound like an easier way to transfer tokens.

What is a good approach to create functionality similar to ERC20 tokens? Do I need to make use of assets? Examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the near future there will be a token infrastructure integrated into fabric. Take a look at the [video](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GHQkm41tF76kDR5x5eLzJhzLj9S-0bWf).